# CSS problem with silverlight component position. Cannot set height that i want

Tags: .net, html, css, wpf, silverlight

I want to make simple content page with silverlight with next requirments:
Page must contains:

1. top space for banners(html)
2. center - silverlight component. and he will stretch to fitt page.
3. bottom space for banners(html)

Looks quite easy but i faced problem with internet explorer 8.
Silverlight component have small size and doesnot stretch. In others browsers its works fine.

Styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body
    {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #silverlightControlHost
    {
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" style="overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <table  frame="none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border:0px solid White;
        padding: 0px;">
        <tr style="background-color: Red; height: 30px; width: 100%;">
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: Blue; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <td>
                <div id="silverlightControlHost" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: Black;">
                              <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
                    width="100%" height="100%">
                    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/test.xap" />
                    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                    <param name="background" value="white" />
                    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
                    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Получить Microsoft Silverlight"
                            style="border-style: none" />
                    </a>
                </object>
                <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
                    border: 0px"></iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: Red; height: 30px; width: 100%;">
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Chrome(works perfect):

[image]

IE8(not so good):

[image]

What wrong with it? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id stay away from using tables for layout, but thats just me :)

Firstly i would create a holding div for the layout, two divs for the top and bottom and inbetween the silverlight control host div, like

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
    </div>
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
            width="100%" height="100%">
            <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap" />
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
            <param name="background" value="white" />
            <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
            <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: 0px"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

what you need to do is switch position to absolute in the silverlightControlHost class, and align the control to stretch over the page, leaving space on top and bottom for your html div containers something like

```
#silverlightControlHost 
{
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    bottom:30px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and heres the css classes for the other divs

```
#top
{
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
}

#bottom{
   height:30px; 
   width:100%;
   bottom:0px;
   position:absolute;
} 

#container
{ 
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

it was discovered that bottom was not positioned to the bottom :)

```
#bottom{
   height:30px; 
   width:100%;
   bottom:0px;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for quick reply. It really saves a lot of time. Sorry, that maybe such easy question but i new to html. So thanks a lot.

Comment: I set   background-color:Red; and noticed, that bottom container actually not at the bottom of the screen. :( How can i move it down?

Comment: And one more problem with ie 7. The property height:100% doesnot work at all. Content always not visible! Please help :(

Comment: perhaps then set containers class to position:absolute;right:0px;left:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px;

Comment: post another question linking to this one, i dont have ie7